# Matlab error Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded meshgrid

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, size

I have a data file having 20 columns. I'm using 2 columns of my data file (total 100 vector)

I'm using matlab R2015a 64bit on iMac (Memory 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 | processor 3.5 GHz Intel Core i5)

when I delete some data and use 80 vectors (data) I get this error

> *Requested 5370401x5615001 (224670.8GB) array exceeds maximum array
>   size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a
>   long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size
>   limit or preference panel for more information.*

And when I use all the data 100 vectors I get this error.

> Error using repmat Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

I am using the code below.

```
data=csvread('test.csv'); 
findLength = data(:,[2:3]); 


 L = length(findLength); disp(L);
d2 = data(:, 2);
d3 = data(:, 3);
[idx,C] = kmeans(data,2);
x1 = min(d2):0.01:max(d2);
x2 = min(d3):0.01:max(d3);
[x1G,x2G] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
```

**UPDATE**
Largest number in column 2 is 56159 and in column 3 is 73498.

Comment: how do you delete "some data"? and what is the size of `x1` and `x2`. It seems due to the size of those vector (5370401x5615001) the meshgrid is producing a very large matrix. The first option is to change `0.01` to `1` to see if your memory is enough for that.

Comment: @NKN I tried to make my minimize my data set by reducing the number of data from 100 to 80. I was following the tutorial from mathworks so x1 and x2 are suppose to help in finding the distance from each centroid to points

Comment: @NKN kmeans  tutorial on training kmean cluster from the first example http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#inputarg_k

Comment: I do not see such big matrices in the tutorial though.

Comment: What is the size of x1 and x2? The suggestion from NKN, by changing 0.01 to 1 would not be sufficient as this would only lower the memory usage by a factor 1000, thus it would still require ~22.5 GB of memory.